# Inserting a Blank Record When Inserting into data into phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

i am relatively new to the php coding life and i need some help. when i am inserting data into my phpmyadmin account it inserts the record i would like but it also inserts just a blank record? Suggestions? also new to this site if theres any gaps in coding they arent actually there.

```
<?php

$host="xxxxx";
$username="xxxxx";
$password="xxxxx";
$db_name="xxxxx";
$tbl_name="LimitlessInventory";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("Cannot Connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("Cannot Select Database");

$year=$_POST['year'];
$make=$_POST['make'];
$model=$_POST['model'];
$price=$_POST['price'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$buyme=$_POST['buyme'];


echo "$year";
echo "$make";
echo "$model";
echo "$price";
echo "$description";
echo "$buyme";

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(year, make, model, price, description, buyme)VALUES('$year', '$make', '$model', '$price', '$description', '$buyme')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close();

?>
<html>
<body>
<title>Limitless Auto</title>
<form action="LimitlessInsert2.php" method="POST">
Year: <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" name="year" value="Ex.2012"><br />
Make: <input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="make" value="Ex.Chevrolet"><br />
Model: <input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="model" value="Ex.Corvette"><br />
Price: <input type="text" size="9" maxlength="9" name="price" value="Ex.$15,999.00"><br />
Description: <input type="text" size="75" maxlength="255" name="description"         value="Ex.2000 Miles 5.7L V8 Red"><br />
Link: <input type="text" size="255" maxlength="255" name="buyme" value="<a     href=http://solemnprophecy.com/DAT201/LimitlessBuyNow.php>Buy_ME!</a>"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<a href="http://solemnprophecy.com/DAT201/LimitlessInventory.php">Inventory Page</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What has this got to do with phpmyadmin?

Comment: The datatype of field in database and your input could be mismatching.

Comment: You've just posted code that clearly shows an SQL injection on a live website, i'm not sure that was wise

Comment: wow guys,! its because he's not trapping the submit event so its inserting a blank row on page load and then a populated row when he posts his form

Comment: it was doing it before i put that line in

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this line `Link: <input type="text" size="255" maxlength="255" name="buyme" value="<a     href=http://solemnprophecy.com/DAT201/LimitlessBuyNow.php>Buy_ME!</a>"><br />` Try adding quotes `value="<a href='http://solemnprophecy.com/DAT201/LimitlessBuyNow.php'>Buy_ME!</a>">`

Comment: i know this is dumb but its actually just inserting a link into the database to click when the user wants to click it but i need it for each record

Comment: You should consider adding a conditional statement like this `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` before your `$year=$_POST['year'];`

Comment: Under which column is it inserting a blank entry?

Comment: Plus, if an input field is left blank, then yeah... it will insert a blank entry. That's because you're not checking for empty inputs. Use a conditional statement like `if(empty($_POST['year'])){ die("You need to fill this."); }`

Comment: it was inserting a 0 into the year category so i believe it to be that field and ill try that

Comment: Therefore my theory was `bang on` then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

// Db Connection Details
$host="xxx";
$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$db_name="xxx";
$tbl_name="LimitlessInventory";

// Handle Post
if (isset($_POST['cmd']) && $_POST['cmd'] == 'Add')
{
    // Extract Post Vars
    extract($_POST);

    // Connect To DB
    mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("Cannot Connect");
    mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("Cannot Select Database");

    // Insert Row
    mysql_query(sprintf("INSERT INTO $tbl_name(year, make, model, price, description, buyme) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($year),
        mysql_real_escape_string($make),
        mysql_real_escape_string($model),
        mysql_real_escape_string($price),
        mysql_real_escape_string($description),
        mysql_real_escape_string($buyme))) or die('Failed to insert row - '. mysql_error());

    // Close DB
    mysql_close();

    // Success
    echo "Data added";
}

?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    Year: <input type="text" size="4" maxlength="4" name="year" value="Ex.2012"><br />
    Make: <input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="make" value="Ex.Chevrolet"><br />
    Model: <input type="text" size="12" maxlength="12" name="model" value="Ex.Corvette"><br />
    Price: <input type="text" size="9" maxlength="9" name="price" value="Ex.$15,999.00"><br />
    Description: <input type="text" size="75" maxlength="255" name="description" value="Ex.2000 Miles 5.7L V8 Red"><br />
    Link: <input type="text" size="255" maxlength="255" name="buyme" value='<a href=http://solemnprophecy.com/DAT201/LimitlessBuyNow.php>Buy_ME!</a>'><br />
    <input type="submit" name="cmd" value="Add">
</form>
```

As a word of advice, avoid mysql library, it's obsolete now. Use `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using MySQL database. PhpMyAdmin is just a tool to manage the database.

The easiest way to solve would be

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(year, make, model, price, description, buyme)VALUES('$year', '$make', '$model', '$price', '$description', '$buyme')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you said about your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686505/inserting-a-blank-record-when-inserting-into-data-into-phpmyadmin#comment30979276_20686505) *"it was inserting a `0` into the year category so i believe it to be that field and ill try that"*

If an input field is left blank, then yes, it will insert a blank entry.

That's because you're not checking for empty inputs.

Use conditional statements like:

```
if(empty($_POST['year'])){ 
die("You need to fill this."); 
}
```

and wrap your code inside another conditional statement to avoid premature execution.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
...
}
```